# Forgot PIN to unlock lock screen on Nokia C110

Tags: lock-screens, password, locked-out, nokia

My relative put a PIN password on his Nokia C110. He forgot the password and cannot get into it.

I have tried to factory reset the phone, holding volume up and power, holding volume down and power (which showed fastboot mode at the bottom of the screen, but I am not able to click on it or highlight it). I have tried to contact the carrier for the phone and everything they told me to do, I had already tried and it isn't working. If I hold volume up and power, it either stays blank or keeps popping up the android logo.

What can I do? I tried to use Find My Device through Google and it can't even trace the device.

Comment: In fastboot mode there is no touchscreen. Just vol up/down key for change selection and power key to select.